# jQuery Ajax beforeSend does not works in Firefox

Tags: jquery, django, cross-browser, http-headers

I'm trying to execute an ajax-post request using jQuery, and I need to add custom headers (for dJango CSRF). I've tried some code like this:

```
var load = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax/get_page/',
        data: $.toJSON({
            section: section,
            subsection: subsection,
            page: page.page
        }),
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("exmpl", "abcdef");
        },
        success: function (data){
            container.html(data);
            page.init(container);
            show();
        }
    });
}
```

And it works fine in Chrome, but doesn't work in Firefox (Fedora, Firefox 8, jQuery 1.7). It seems that it don't even execute beforeSend function.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the beforeSend failing, or the xhr.setRequestHeader("exmpl", "abcdef");   What if you just alert('something'); in there?

Comment: I've tried alerting in befireSend, and failed. In Firefox beforeSend is not executed at all =(

Comment: Not that this helps you at all, but I just tried it in Firefox 8 and it worked fine. Seems like, based on how you tagged this post, you have a few different JS libraries loaded.  Try starting a page from scratch with only jQuery and your own script and make basic ajax calls.  Then, 1 by 1, add the other external references in until you can re-break it.  Not really an answer - just something worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here, but $.ajax.beforeSend should work just fine in Firefox, however there is a known problem with setRequestHeader in Firefox, and it usually needs to have the XMLHttpRequest opened before it can run setRequestHeader, but this is in native javascript, and I'm not sure if jQuery has fixed this internally somehow?

Something like :

```
xhr.open(method,url,async,username,password); 
xhr.setrequestheader("exmpl", "abcdef");
```

Check firebug for something like "Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x804b000f [nsixmlhttprequest.setrequestheader]" to see if that is the error logged, or if there are any other errors logged, post them here.

EDIT: On the other hand when reading the documentation for $.ajax it says:

> At present, due to a bug in Firefox where .getAllResponseHeaders()
>   returns the empty string although .getResponseHeader('Content-Type')
>   returns a non-empty string, automatically decoding JSON CORS responses
>   in Firefox with jQuery is not supported.

Don't know if this has something to do with your problem, since it's not really the same function, but it sounds somewhat related, there's a workaround on the [jQuery pages](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for Ajax.